# Are there sprinkler system timers that measure flow rate?

Tags: irrigation

Are there sprinkler system timers that measure flow rate (e.g., in ft³/min. or gallons/min.) in addition to time? For example, I could tell it to deliver 100 ft³ of water, and it would automatically know how long to run it to deliver that quantity of water.

Comment: The amount of water provided would be dependent on your water pressure. I don't think anything like that would be accurate seeing water pressure varies from place to place and even house to house on the same street. What are you planning on watering using that amount?

Comment: @Jude I'm thinking of a system that measures the flow-rate using in-line digital flow meters. Such digital meters already exist for recording a house's total city water usage.

Comment: Dumb of me as I forgot about that. Since I live in an area that gets almost excessive rainfall (except for 2 months in mid-summer), we don't have water metres for individual houses.

Comment: @Geremia, I know this isn't what you're looking for, but I think concept is the same. http://www.melnor.com/101-automatic-water-shut-off

Comment: @Ben Yes, that is something like what I'm looking for. thanks

Comment: @geremia If you use flow meter with automatic shut off, wouldn't watering time be dependent on water pressure and sprinkler capacity? (Lower water presure/flow = longer watering time, higher water pressure/flow = shorter time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically non-agriculturally based irrigation (in the US) is measured in gallons per minute by controllers.  The most common monitoring is for high / low flow on zones, though some controllers will also monitor for high flow mainline situations.  The accuracy of the  measurements depend on type of sensor and size of pipe.  I'm curious to know more about your use.

If you know the total GPM for the zone, and the precipitation rate of the nozzles of the zone you can calculate how many inches of water you want to put down.  From there, you can calculate how the frequency and length of time needed to put down a certain volume of water.

I can help with the math if you're interested.

Comment: @pnuts Yes, I'm not interested in how to do it (I know how) but if there are systems that you can tell how much water to put down.

Comment: Not that I've seen.

Comment: I'm sorry that people seem unhappy with my answer.  Since I don't believe such a system exists, I was trying to offer a solution that would get the OP to the same end result.  I know it's not what the OP was asking, but it was the best way I could come up with help.